# Return programmatically instance of a class but a little different

Tags: c#, methods, interface, abstract

First, I'm a complete Noob.

Here's my problem, I have a form with a TabPageControl and some TabPages.

I created a class "TabPageSelector".
In this class I can add what TabPage has a DataGridView, TextBox, ComboBox enz
It also keeps track of what the current TabPage is.
In for example this method I want the TabPageSelector to return the claas for TabPage1

```
private void cb_Members_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BaseTabPageHandler t = TabPageSelector.ReturnPageHandlerInstance();
        t.Members_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
        _reloadDataGrid(t._baseSqlString());
    }
```

I have now a abstract class "BaseTabPageHandler" and a tabpage1Handler and tabpage2Handler
the 2 tabpageHandlers share some code defined in the abstract class

Now my question, how do i return the right class and what do i have to return.
Do i return a Interface or the BaseTabPageHandler.

What i now have doesn't work, because I cannot access the t._baseSqlString() method.
This method is declaired in de tabpageHandles class.

Members_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e); work because i declaired it in de BaseTabPageHandler as a method

```
    public abstract class BaseTabPageHandler : ITabPageHandler
{
    public string cert { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    public abstract string _basesqlstring(int visible = 1);


    public void Members_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
        string _customerId = cb.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 7);
        string _customerName = cb.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(10);
        Console.WriteLine(_customerName);
        if (_customerId == "0051956")
        {
            cert = "intersafe";
        }
        else
        {
            cert = "essilor";
        }
    }

    public void Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, TextBox tb)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


}


public interface ITabPageHandler
{
    string cert { get; set; }
    string type { get; set; }

    string _basesqlstring(int visible = 1);

    void Members_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);

    void Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, TextBox tb);
}


public class tabpage1Handler : BaseTabPageHandler, ITabPageHandler
{

    public override string _basesqlstring(int visible = 1)
    {
        return "where [safetycertificate] = '" + cert + "' and [usage] = '" + type + "' and [visible] = " + visible;
    }
}


public class tabpage2Handler : BaseTabPageHandler, ITabPageHandler
{

    public void GridView_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e, DataGridView gv)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public override string _basesqlstring(int visible = 1)
    {
        return "where [safetycertificate] = '" + cert + "' and [usage] = '" + type;
    }
}


public class TabPageSelector
{
    static private Dictionary<string, DataGridView> _gridViews = new Dictionary<string, DataGridView>();
    static private Dictionary<string, TextBox> _TextBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
    static private Dictionary<string, TabPage> _TabPages = new Dictionary<string, TabPage>();
    static private string _currentTabPage;
    static private Employee _user;

    public static void AddUser(Employee user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

    public static void AddTabPage(TabPage TP)
    {
        if (_user == null) throw new Exception("Please add the user to the selector before adding a TabPage!!!");
        string name = TP.Name.ToLower();
        if(_TabPages.ContainsKey(name) == false)
        {
            if (_TabPages.Count == 0) _currentTabPage = name;
            _TabPages.Add(name, TP);
            if(TP.Tag != null &&
               TP.Tag.ToString() == "IsAdmin" &&
               _user.IsAdmin == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TabPage ("+name+") Locked...");
                TP.Text = "*Blocked*";
                //TP.Visible = false; // this hides the controls on it.
                TP.Enabled = false; // this disables the controls on it
            }
        }
    }

    public static ITabPageHandler ReturnPageHandlerInstance()
    {
        string className = _currentTabPage + "Handler";
        string assemblyName = "BreukRegClassLibrary.TabPageHandlers."+className;

        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        ITabPageHandler t = assembly.CreateInstance(assemblyName) as ITabPageHandler;

        return t;
    }


    public static void SelectTabPage(string TabPage)
    {
        _currentTabPage = TabPage.ToLower();
    }

    public static void AddGridView(string TabPage, DataGridView DGV)
    {
        if(_gridViews.ContainsKey(TabPage.ToLower()) == false)
        {
            DGV.AutoSize = false;
            _gridViews.Add(TabPage, DGV);
        }
    }

    public static void AddTextBox(string TabPage, TextBox TB)
    {
        if (_TextBoxes.ContainsKey(TabPage.ToLower()) == false)
        {
            _TextBoxes.Add(TabPage, TB);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post more code of yours , unable to get clear picture on what you want

Comment: Just use Generics combined with a type constraint

Comment: First, I'm a complete Noob. Just use Generics combined with a type constraint?!?!?!